# magento 2 Get Top Search Terms

Tags: magento2.2.2, search-terms

Is there a way to get the 5 tops search terms like in the Dashboard as `array` without having to query database->table directly sorting them popularity limit 5?

Answer (score 1):

Found a way using `Magento\Search\Model\ResourceModel\Query\CollectionFactory`

```
...
$searchCollection =  $this->_queryCollectionFactory->create()
   ->setPopularQueryFilter($this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId())
   ->setPageSize(5)
   ->load()
   ->getItems();

    foreach($searchCollection as $k=>$v) {
        echo $vv->getQueryText().', ';
    }
       ...
```